# Converting PEM certificate format to DER format in C++

Tags: c, encryption, certificate, stm32

I am trying to convert PEM certificate ---

```
char cert[] = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        "MIID0TCCArmDQEBCwUAMDwxFzAVBgNV\n"
        "BAMMDmp1YW5nYnVyZ29zIENBMSEwHwYDVQQKDBhqdWFuZ2J1cmdvcyBPcmdhbml6\n"
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\0";
```

to

DER format {
0x30, 0x82, 0x03, 0xD7, 0x30,
}

for STM micro controller .. is there any library or example.

Comment: PEM is actually a Base64 encoded DER, so you can just drop off certificate header and footer (BEGIN CERTIFICATE, END CERTIFICATE lines) and call some Base64 decoder (more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail). And if you want some lib you can look for something like mbedtls: check mbedtls_x509_crt_parse() at https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/x509_crt.h.

Comment: You could use the openssl bio_ functions for this I think. Look at the source code for the x509 or pkcs7 tool, for library usage.

Comment: BTW you don't need `\0` for a double quoted string like that, it's added by the compiler. And 0xd7 becomes 0xd1 in the correct answer.

Comment: If you want to do this from the microcontroller, WolfSSL has such functionality. If you can do this on PC and then use the already converted certificate, you can use OpenSSL to convert it on PC.

Comment: Have a look to mbeddTLS. It is included in STMicro code example package (STM32 Cube)